# Column values match values in a list

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe and and a list:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Orig'] = ['CA', 'OH', 'WA','CA','CA','IN','FL']
df['Dest'] = ['CA', 'CA', 'OH','WA','MI','WA','MA']

lst = ['WA','CA','OH']
```

I would like to do the follwing...
If value for Orig and Dest is the lst, then set column Category to 'T', else 'F'. How can I accomplish that? Thank you.

orig dest

```
0   CA   CA  
1   OH   CA  
2   WA   OH  
3   CA   WA  
4   CA   MI  
5   IN   WA  
6   FL   MA
```

Desire output:

```
  orig dest category  
0   CA   CA        T  
1   OH   CA        T  
2   WA   OH        T  
3   CA   WA        T  
4   CA   MI        F  
5   IN   WA        F  
6   FL   MA        F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isin` and `all` to generate a boolean series for `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df['category'] = np.where(df.isin(lst).all(axis=1), 'T', 'F')
```

Or, if more columns in the input, restrict to the chosen ones by slicing:

```
df['category'] = np.where(df[['orig', 'dest']].isin(lst).all(axis=1), 'T', 'F')
```

Alternatively, you can also select with: `df['orig'].isin(lst) & df['dest'].isin(lst)`.

Output:

```
  Orig Dest category
0   CA   CA        T
1   OH   CA        T
2   WA   OH        T
3   CA   WA        T
4   CA   MI        F
5   IN   WA        F
6   FL   MA        F
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.assign(col1=df.isin(lst).all(axis=1)\
          .map({True:'T',False:'F'}))
    
     Orig Dest col1
    0   CA   CA    T
    1   OH   CA    T
    2   WA   OH    T
    3   CA   WA    T
    4   CA   MI    F
    5   IN   WA    F
    6   FL   MA    F
```